# How to connect oracle 32 bit client from .net 64 bit framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, database-connection

I have an oracle 12C 32 bit client. I can't update the client to 64 bit as it is the requirement. How do I connect this to.net 64 bit framework? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Simple answer: it is not possible. You could use the Managed Driver which support either architecture.

Comment: You can install both Oracle client, follow this instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100